# Delay UISearchbar parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchbar in my app. This is a dynamic search and as the user enters text, a remote database is searched via a remote API call (I think it is through REST).

The table view gets refreshed dynamically, as the user types. I am using NSXMLParser for parsing the XML results. (so 3 delegate methods; didStartElement, didEndElement)

In some cases, there are duplicate entries shown in the results
e.g. If user has typed YAH, it shows YAHOO 3-4 times. I'm not sure why.

How can I reduce the number of times the parsing is done, or how to delay the parsing, so that it does not make a request for every character entered/deleted by the user.

This, I am assuming, might fix the problem.

Comment: I am open to all kinds of solutions/ possible fixes.

Comment: Please provide me some additional possible fixes.

Answer (score 10):

One thing you can do is introduce a delay before you send off the remote API call, instead of sending one query for every character.

```
// Whenever UISearchbar text changes, schedule a lookup
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)text {
        // cancel any scheduled lookup
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
        // start a new one in 0.3 seconds
        [self performSelector:@selector(doRemoteQuery) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
}
```

Comment: For doRemoteQuery, how do I write if I want to pass a parameter ?

Comment: You write the method with the parameter then it would look like `[self performSelector:@selector(doRemoteQuery:) withObject:myObject afterDelay:0.3];`

Comment: If you want to pass a parameter, you would do `withObject:myParameter`, instead of `withObject:nil`. Caution: in that case, you'll need to think carefully about the retain/release mechanisms you use for the parameter object so you don't leak memory or release the object too soon.

Comment: ok..thanks..ur code worked fine..but the issue of duplicate search results is still there..

Answer (score 0):

Here are the relevant parts of a method I use in one of my apps to remove duplicates from a web service result.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableResults = [[myResults mutableCopy] autorelease];
NSMutableSet *duplicates = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableIndexSet *indexesToRemove = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];

for (NSString *result in mutableResults)
{
    if (![duplicates containsObject:result])
        [duplicates addObject:result];
    else 
        [indexesToRemove addIndex:[mutableResults indexOfObject:object]];
}

[mutableResults removeObjectsAtIndexes:duplicates];
return mutableResults;
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be along what I am looking for. But I have a question. I have 2 views; List & Detail. The list view has search bar and the rows in this list view get loaded from web service results. The detail view uses the shared singleton array to display it's data. 

So your solution seems to fix the list view. How will I go about the detail view ?

Comment: Instead of giving the detail view controller access to the entire dataset, you should just pass the data for one item in the array from your list view to your detail view.